# push via ssh not working

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

Windows 10, using git via the Git Bash program installed. I have this working for bitbucket. I can't seem to get this working though with my server.

Have my keys on the Windows laptop: ~.ssh\id_rsa.pub & ~.ssh\id_rsa
The laptops public key is also on the server in the correct `authorized_keys` file

```
git remote add tillvaxt ssh://root@example.com:51022/srv/repo/tillvaxt.git
git add . -A
git commit -a
git push tillvaxt master
example.com's password:
```

How does one het to the root of the issue here? It doesn't exactly give one much information to work with.

Answer (score 0):

After logging on my linux laptop and looking at all of the files the issue was found.

I had a ssh connection to my server working with my windows laptop via kitty. I added my key to a openssh docker container (I run two ssh servers, one for root server access, one for the specific container).

After adding my new key to the authorized_file in the docker container kittys terminal seemed to mess up the line breakings in the file, resulting in a very weird key mixup. It should be one key per row but the ssh-rsa bit was shifted to the end of the next line. I just fixed the lines and saved = works.

Comment: doesn't really seem it's about windows, but about one specific software and its use. SO is not really about bashing operating systems, so I've edited some of those out.

Comment: I disagree. KiTTY is built on top of PuTTY which is the default standard. This is what the Windows environment and community offers, products which don't work properly.